# Google chat codelabs error when deploy (OperationError: code=3)

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-codelab

I followed [official google chat codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-chat-poll-bot#4), but in the last step when I run `gcloud functions deploy app --trigger-http --security-level=secure-always`, I got anerror:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'googleapis' of undefined

I did follow all instruction, work fine until I run `npm install --save googleapis` and require that library on my code.

here my error code:

```
const { buildConfigurationForm, MAX_NUM_OF_OPTIONS } = require('./config-form');
const { buildVoteCard } = require('./vote-card');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

`googleapis` is already on package.json and also package-lock.json.

here my package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "poll-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^110.0.0"
  }
}
```

but why I still fail ? I just follow the tutorial from the official codelabs by google?

if I remove googleapis using command `npm remove googleapis` it will return another error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Only after I remove `const {google} = require('googleapis');` and all related code, it can successfully deployed. But I want to use `googleapis` library as the codelabs instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened because of a different node version. My local(GCP CLI console) is node 18, but the google cloud function runtime is 14.

My solution is to remove `package-lock.json`.

But I think it's better to use the same version between CLI and GCF.